# Keyboard not working with Qemu emulation of Linux 5.19.8 kernel?

Tags: linux

I have built a custom kernel (5.19.8) and have tried running it with Qemu. I am able to launch a busybox shell, however the keyboard is not working.

I thought I had done this in the past and did not need any additional parameters, but could be wrong.

Any advice?